# eureka: Custom clientFilter is useless

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-netflix

> For more complex needs you can create a @Bean of type
>   DiscoveryClientOptionalArgs and inject ClientFilter instances into it,
>   all of which will be applied to the calls from the client to the
>   server.

this description in spring-cloud wiki

```
@Bean
    public DiscoveryClientOptionalArgs discoveryClientOptionalArgs() {
        DiscoveryClientOptionalArgs discoveryClientOptionalArgs = new DiscoveryClientOptionalArgs();
        discoveryClientOptionalArgs.setAdditionalFilters(Collections.singletonList(new IpCilentFilter()));
        return discoveryClientOptionalArgs;
    }


public class IpCilentFilter extends ClientFilter {
    @Override
    public ClientResponse handle(ClientRequest clientRequest) throws ClientHandlerException {
        // here How to disallow clients to connect
        return getNext().handle(clientRequest);
    }
}
```

How to disallow clients to connect?

1. throws `ClientHandlerException`  useless
2. return `null` useless

what should I do？

Comment: Can you expound on what "useless" means? What are the actual results when you try these things? My guess (I've not written a Jersey client filter before) is that you'd return an appropriate `ClientResponse`.

Comment: for example, can clientFilter prohibit an IP connection to eureka? How to achieve it

Comment: You know this is a client side filter correct? It won't restrict anything on the eureka server.

Comment: I understand it wrong, I go to learn jersey clientFilter

Comment: You can write a custom security filter on the eureka server side and have custom security.